# Create a column that computes a formula with numbers from e.g. row[a] + column[a]

Tags: r

How do I code something that creates a new column into my data frame that computes this formula and then rounding the numbers: (p(1−p))/(SE^2)

"p(1)" is from column[a] row[a] while "SE(1)" is from column[b] row[a].

Comment: Have you tried writing some R code for this yet?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Not yet, because I got absolutely no idea how to do this. I am new to R.